# random slope and intercept with categorical predictor - multilevel model

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, random-effects-model

I'm working with micro-data about graduates and I'm testing the origin effect (father class) by fields of education on the first-entry labour market income controlling for both educational and labour market covariates. However, as second step, I'm interesting in testing whether this effect is heterogeneous across the 110 Italian provinces.

For this purpose, I was thinking to apply a multilevel model with a random intercept and random slope on my main predictor - father origin class - groping by province. However, here I have my problem: is it possible and what's the meaning of adding a random slope-intercept on a factor variable? and in case, how to proper specify the model?

I only used continuous variable as main predictor in my previous LMM and if this was the case I would have fit the following:

```
 lme(log_wage ~ father_class + Fields_education + age_class + score*public_private
 + graduate_class + Q1_22 + relevel(Q2_9, ref="YES") + Q2_12 + Q2_19 + Q2_15 + (1 + father_class | province), males, weights = COEFFIN, REML=F)
```

But since father_class is a factor variable with 7 levels, I don't know how to properly define the mixed model and how to correctly interpret it.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to fit random slopes for `father_class` ?

Comment: Because I expect that the effect of father_class is heterogeneous by provinces and specifically stronger in provinces of the South. Therefore, I was thinking to use a multilevel model

Comment: Then you've answered your own question :)

Comment: But I still have concerns on how to correctly implement a random slope-intercept on a categorical variable and how to correctly interpret it. I mean, I guess there's a substantial difference - above all in the covariance matrix - between continuous and categorical predictor with a random slope-intercept. Do you have any comments on that? thanks :)

Comment: If you want to allow for the effect of one variable (categorical or not) to vary within levels of a grouping variable, then you add it as a random slope, just like you did.

Comment: and the interpretation of the random effects does not change neither?